# Linq2SQL not inserting related entity

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to insert into two releated tables with linq2sql but my code only inserts one entity(Email), I dont get any exceptions - just the other entity (attachment) is not inserted.

I think I have an mistake somewhere in the association, but i cant figure out how to set it up properly.

Thanks for help.

Insert code:

```
using (TransactionScope main_transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)))
            {

                foreach (var attachment in attachmets)
                    email.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                _emails.InsertOnSubmit(email);

                _context.SubmitChanges();

                main_transaction.Complete();
            }
```

---

Pocos:

```
[Table(Name = "maily")]
internal class Email
{
    private EntitySet<Attachment> _attachments;

    public Email()
    {
        this._attachments = new EntitySet<Attachment>(); 
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, Name = "ID_mailu", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public virtual int ID_mailu { get; set; }



    [Association(Storage = "_attachments", OtherKey = "id_mailu")]
    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments
    {
        get { return _attachments.ToList(); }
        set { _attachments.Assign(value); }
    }
}

[Table(Name = "MailPrilohy")]
internal class Attachment
{
    private EntityRef<Email> _email;

    public Attachment()
    {
        _email = default(EntityRef<Email>);
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey =true, IsDbGenerated = true, Name = "id_prilohy", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id_Prilohy { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "id_mailu", CanBeNull = false, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int id_mailu { get; set; }

    [Association(Storage = "_email", ThisKey = "id_mailu", OtherKey = "ID_mailu", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Email Email
    {
        get { return _email.Entity; }
        set { _email.Entity = value; }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The database submit doesn't happen until you call `SubmitChanges`. There is no tangible cost associated with multiple calls to `InsertOnSubmit` - so why not you call `insertonsubmit()` 2 times ?

Comment: Both entities are tied by foreign key. Making sepearete submits means separate transactions and checking if both inserts were fine, if the second one would be wrong i would have to delete first - thats just impractical as hell, thats why i hoped to use Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have just solved the problem...

The problem was in several places.

1s was the association missed foreign key attribute ..

```
[Association(Storage = "_email", ThisKey = "id_mailu", OtherKey = "ID_mailu", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public Email Email
        {
            get { return _email.Entity; }
            set { _email.Entity = value;}
        }
```

Next, i was supposed to insert attachments -> not the email.

```
_context.Attachments.InsertAllOnSubmit(attachmets);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to see if this works for you?

```
using (TransactionScope main_transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)))
            {

                foreach (var attachment in attachmets)
                    attachment.Email = email; // only this line changed

                _emails.InsertOnSubmit(email);

                _context.SubmitChanges();

                main_transaction.Complete();
            }
```

Comment: Still not working. Email entity was inserted but not Attachments.

Comment: Just to make sure, with the debugger, have a look at the _context.GetChangeSet().Inserts. I guess it's only the email there.

Comment: You are right, it seems that a line ... email.Attachments.Add(attachment); does nothing but why?

Comment: Are you sure there are any attachments?